# Image Height Constraint Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, autolayout

I have a UIImageView and used autolayout to add height and width constraints (and other ones as well). There are no conflicting constraints or warnings. I am querying an image from a database and setting the imageview's image to that image. However, the image is showing up with a much larger height than I have specified via constraints. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

This line should resolve your problem :

```
yourImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

You can do it in Storyboard by checking the "Clip Subviews" of your UIImageView element.

Answer (score 1):

1. ```
   YourImageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
   ```

   Maybe the problem is coming because of your contentMode ,so please your imageView content mode.
2. If you are developing application for a single phone then use aspect fit for that[constraints]

Comment: You can do that in the Storyboard as well. Under _Attribute inspector_ in the right side panel, and then under _View_, you can change _Concent Mode_ to "Aspect Fit".

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting image from server then you should resize the image according to your imageView size ...its a best practice.